# XSLT selects only one object

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to select from an XML document a collection of Locations for a Business.  This code works except that is only selects one item.  So, my question: is there something that I can do to this code to make it work for each Location?

```
    <xsl:template match="/InstitutionAlias/InstitutionAliasExternalReferenceCollection">
  <InstitutionExternalReferenceCollection>    
    <xsl:for-each select="InstitutionAliasExternalReference">
      <InstitutionExternalReference>
        <ExternalReferenceIdentifier>
          <xsl:value-of select="ExternalReferenceIdentifier"/>
        </ExternalReferenceIdentifier>
      </InstitutionExternalReference>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </InstitutionExternalReferenceCollection>
</xsl:template>
```

This is what the output should look like

```
  <InstitutionExternalReferenceCollection>
- <InstitutionExternalReference>
  <ExternalReferenceIdentifier>Test1</ExternalReferenceIdentifier>
</InstitutionExternalReference>

- <InstitutionExternalReference>
  <ExternalReferenceIdentifier>Test2</ExternalReferenceIdentifier>
</InstitutionExternalReference>
```

Here is a sample xml file.

```
  - <InstitutionAliasExternalReferenceCollection>
- <InstitutionAliasExternalReference>
  <ExternalReferenceIdentifier>Test1</ExternalReferenceIdentifier>
</InstitutionAliasExternalReference>
- <InstitutionAliasExternalReference>
  <ExternalReferenceIdentifier>Test2</ExternalReferenceIdentifier>
</InstitutionAliasExternalReference>
```

Comment: I believe that you should wrap your choose tag with a for-each tag, setting the select attribute of the for-each tag to /Business/LocationCollection.  'code' <xsl:for-each select="/Business/LocationCollection">
    <xsl:choose>...</xsl:choose></xsl:for-each>

Comment: `for-each` is best avoided in XSLT.

Comment: Use applyTemplates if you want to match further elements. Besides, there's no LocationCollection in your example input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? It could be condensed if you were sure each business could have only one location identifier (I don't know) but I decided to keep things separated into separate templates.

You can run it at [this XMLPlayground](http://www.xmlplayground.com/wlKKZ4) (see output source).

```
    <!-- kick things off -->
    <xsl:template match="BusinessCollection">
        <BusinessCollection>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='Business' />
        </BusinessCollection>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- each business -->
    <xsl:template match='Business'>
        <Business>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='LocationIdentifier' />
        </Business>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- each location identifier -->
    <xsl:template match='LocationIdentifier'>
        <LocationIdentifier>
            <xsl:value-of select='.' />
        </LocationIdentifier>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Your expected output mentioned `Data` nodes, but these didn't appear in your XSL attempt so I'm not sure what the intention was there.

Comment: Sorry, the field names are obtuse so I thought it would be better to edit them to something reasonable. I edited this question to use real data.  I have tried the foreach but it just won't select more than one InstitutionExternalReference.

Comment: Utkanos,  your solution works nicely.  I did get my for-each to work too. Not sure which is preferable.

Comment: for-each loops are always best avoided in XSLT. Templated solutions provide more scalability and flexibility.

Comment: @user1549583 XSL is a declarative language and foreach loops seem like a very procedural mechanism. Using templates makes it much easier to modify your stylesheet in case of changes.